# Use Laurent series to compute the residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I know you have to use the Laurent series to solve this problem, since the function has an essential singularity.

$$ \oint\limits_{\gamma} e^{\frac{1}{z}}\,\mathrm{d}z = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} \lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 0} \partial_z^{n-1} z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}} $$

For a closed path $\gamma$ with a winding number of $1$ centered at $0$, I tried to calculate $\partial_z^{n-1} z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}$, but I was unable to find a closed form to calculate the limit.

Comment: Can you apply the residue theorem to a function which has a singularity which is *not* a pole but in fact an essential singularity?

Comment: This is an essential singularity, so you have to use the Laurent series to compute the residue.

Comment: Jeah I know that you have to use lautenseries but it would be cool if you get the same result

Comment: but you can't use that if the function doesn't satisfy the conditions for the residue theorem